Implementing Google consent mode basic and advanced
I'm trying to implement both basic and advanced Google Consent mode for my companies internal cookie management solution but I'm getting a bit confused on the differences of basis and advanced mode in relation to implementing the code.
Basic:
As I understand Google Tags should be blocked until consent is granted. Is that as simple as setting consent types i.e. analytics_storage, ad_storage etc. to denied as default and then updating them to granted on consent?
Advanced:
As I understand Google Tags will not be blocked before consent, instead data will be collected and then upon consent sent to Analytics and/or Ads.
Consent types default does not necessarily have to be denied, and user should have a code less way of setting their defaults (even without using GTM template), with the possibility of adding region specific behavior.
Am I missing something? Like is there more to ensuring Google Tags are being blocked/not blocked? I have seen somewhere that the gtag('config') for basic consent mode is executed only on consent update. Is that best practice?

Basic means you send nothing until consent is granted for the product in question. For example, you will not send GA4 events until analytics is granted.
Advanced means you always send events. i.e. you still send events even if the relevant state is denied.
In both modes, you set the current consent states before sending any events.

So if I understand you correctly it would mean that for basic mode the tracking code should only be added to the site if consent has been granted. Where as it should always exist in advanced mode?

Yes. Basic means no tracking until consent is granted. What many think is the way to comply with the laws.


Basic: As I understand Google Tags should be blocked until consent is
granted. Is that as simple as setting consent types i.e.
analytics_storage, ad_storage etc. to denied as default and then
updating them to granted on consent?

You update the consent types to the state the user chooses using the CMP. And yes, no data is transferred to Google at all until the users grants it.

Advanced: As I understand Google Tags will not be blocked before
consent, instead data will be collected and then upon consent sent to
Analytics and/or Ads.

Partial data is collected before the user gives consent. You can read more about cookieless pings here - https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/10000067#Pings
